# How do I ignore filters in AWS quicksight calculated measures?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a SPICE dataset which holds our sales data with an analysis (& subsequent dashboard) built on top of this.

My stakeholder wants to be able to select a customer and review various metrics *alongside* the overall metrics.

For example if I have a metric for "Average Commisison Rate" I'd want to put "Average Commission Rate - All Customers" in the same visualisation.

I have tried the avgOver function but introducing the customer filters makes both metrics identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a little late but QuickSight has recently released [level aware aggregations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/level-aware-aggregations.html). These allow you to add a calculated field (using `avgOver` in fact) that is run before filters using the `PRE_FILTERS` option.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had seen that update but didn't relate it back to this question - cheers for pointing it out :)